# Reentrant Locks: pros and cons?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

In what situations would one want to use reentrant locks versus normal locks?

Comment: In what situation are you comfortable about deadlocking yourself?

Comment: @HansPassant I don't get it. If you actually have a solid understanding of concurrency, you'll never deadlock in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume a reentrant lock would have some additional overhead compared to a normal lock - to check what thread is acquiring the lock.

Therefore, if you know that under normal operation a thread will only acquire the lock once before releasing it again, you may gain some performance by using a normal lock. This could be particularly beneficial in tight loops, etc.

Answer (score 9):

The main difference between Simple/Regular Locks and Re-entrant Locks is that simple locks allow one thread to acquire a lock at a given point in time, keeping every other thread waiting, including the thread that holds the lock if it tried to lock again. Re-entrant locks allow the same thread to acquire a lock as many times as needed, provided that they already hold the lock, and keeps all other threads in a waiting queue for the same lock.

Re-entrant Locks are generally useful when recursion is needed. Imagine that you have a recursive function that needs to acquire a lock to execute. If you were using a simple lock, your first thread can easily deadlock itself. First iteration of the recursion will acquire the lock successfully, the second iteration will try to acquire the lock again, but will block forever. The second iteration will wait for the first iteration to unlock, but the first iteration will not unlock unless the second iteration completes.

A re-entrant lock is useful here because once a thread holds the lock, it can lock as many times as it pleases after that. Only catch is that your thread will have to unlock as many times as it locked, making it similar to a counting semaphore.

Comment: This is more a description of a reentrant lock and less a discussion of its pros or cons. Why wouldn't you just always use a reentrant lock?

Comment: Although the title of the post mentions pros and cons, the post itself asks for the situations in which re-entrant locks are used instead of simple locks, which is the answer I tried to give. Your post talks about performance differences, which is correct, but does not answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. Fair enough.

Comment: If you create a lock to protect an object, you should hold it while you are working on anything you want to regard as an apparently atomic action. This may include non-recursive calls to other functions where you know the effect of the function but not its implementation. Therefore these non-recursive calls may use information from the object you have locked without you knowing this. Therefore they may attempt to lock this object, without you knowing about them or them knowing about you - their caller. For this to work you need the extra overhead of a recursive lock.